# find the len of the field and update the field if the len is less than 8 in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a column policy_date with datatype varchar

```
Policy_date
-----------
A1999062
20010405
```

I would like to update the data with
case when isnumeric(policy_date) = 0 then trim the alphabet (1999062) and check if the len is less than 8 then make it as NULL else Policy_date.

NOTE: i have to convert the date field to `date` datatype instead of `varchar`.
My out put should look like:

```
Policy_Date
-----------
NULL
2001-04-05
```

Can anyone write the sql case statement .
Thank You,
Swathi.

Comment: i am unable to write the case statement but here is what i tried..
 select   RIGHT([policy_date], LEN([policy_date]) - 1) AS MyTrimmedColumn
  FROM table
 where isnumeric ([policy_date])= 0

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server are you working with?  There have been several functions added since SQL Server 2012 (TRY_PARSE, TRY_CONVERT and TRY_CAST) that can be used to help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment you just want to remove the first character position if it is alpha.  That eliminates the need for a function / CLR call.  If this requirement changes you will need to create a function to strip the chars but the rest of the query will work.

```
Create Table #Test (PolicyDate Varchar(8000))
Insert #Test Values ('A19990602')
Insert #Test Values ('A1999062')
Insert #Test Values ('20010405')

Select  Convert(Date,
        Case When IsNumeric(PolicyDate) = 0 Then 
             Case When Len(PolicyDate) < 9 Then Null
                Else Right(PolicyDate, Len(PolicyDate) -1) End
            Else PolicyDate
            End) PolicyDate2
    From #Test
```

Example function, there are many topics available on which approach is faster.

```
CREATE Function [fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END
    RETURN @strText
END
```

ps.  I used IsNumeric() because that is what you said you wanted to implement.  However take note that by design certian characters can be included and still have the function return that it is a number.  `IsNumeric($1,230.54)` will return a 1.  If that is a concern then use an alternative, for example `TRY_PARSE(PolicyDate as int)` for sql2012 and above.

Comment: Please don't use ISNUMERIC().  SELECT ISNUMERIC($), ISNUMERIC('.'), ISNUMERIC(',')

Comment: Joe c -
i made small change to the #Test query you sent
Create Table #Test (PolicyDate Varchar(8000))
Insert #Test Values ('A19990602')
Insert #Test Values ('A1999062')
Insert #Test Values ('20010405')

Select  Convert(Date,
        Case When IsNumeric(PolicyDate) = 0 Then 
             Case When Len(PolicyDate) < 9 Then ''
                Else Right(PolicyDate, Len(PolicyDate) -1) End
            Else PolicyDate
            End) PolicyDate2
    From #Test
when i made nULL to '' then in the output i am getting date as   1900-01-01 and i want that to be '' .Any suggestions?

Comment: You can only get an empty string if the type is a character (varchar nvarchar char etc). If date then you will get the default value 1900-01-01

Answer (score 0):

You could take the rightmost 8 characters, inject two hyphens with `stuff()`, and check if that is a valid date with `isdate()`. If so, repeat the same and make the conversion with `cast()`:

```
select case when len(policy_date) >= 8 
                 and isdate(stuff(stuff(right(policy_date, 8), 7, '-'), 5, '-')) then
            cast(stuff(stuff(right(policy_date, 8), 7, '-'), 5, '-') as datetime)
       end
```